# How to rotate an object around the center in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have two simple objects in d3.js, they should be circling around the center of the viewport (like planets around the sun).

I am new to d3.js and I know that I have to use transitions but as the planets have to circle all the time and not just on enter or exit I don't know where and how to set the transition.

Here is my current code:

```
var planets = [
    {d:100,r:2},
    {d:150,r:4}
];

var w = 500, h = 400, svg, circle;

function init(){

    svg = d3.select("#drawArea").append("svg").attr({width: w, height: h});

    var center = {
        x: Math.floor(w/2),
        y: Math.floor(h/2)
    };

    svg.append('circle').attr({
        'cx': center.x,
        'cy': center.y,
        'r': 10,
        'class': 'sun'
    });

    circle = svg.selectAll(".planet")
        .data(planets)
        .enter()
            .append("circle")
                .attr("class", "planet")
                .attr("r", function(s){return s.r});

    circle.attr({
        // distance from the center
        'cx': function(s){ return center.x - s.d; },
        // center of the screen
        'cy': function(s){ return center.y; }
    });

}
```

And here is a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcgrabow/52SNU/)** to play around.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to:

1. Place your planets in `g` groups in a `g` that is centered on your sun
2. Create an [`d3.timer`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-d3_timer) in which you rotate your group.

For, example of the use of `d3.timer` see Mike Bostocks [Epicyclic Gearing](http://bl.ocks.org/1353700) example. Using that example, I put together something similar to what you asked: http://bl.ocks.org/4953593

Core of the example:

```
  var w = 800, h = 800;
  var t0 = Date.now();

  var planets = [
    { R: 300, r:  5, speed: 5, phi0: 90},
    { R: 150, r: 10, speed: 2, phi0: 190}
  ];


  var svg = d3.select("#planetarium").insert("svg")
    .attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

  svg.append("circle").attr("r", 20).attr("cx", w/2)
    .attr("cy", h/2).attr("class", "sun")

  var container = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + w/2 + "," + h/2 + ")")

  container.selectAll("g.planet").data(planets).enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "planet").each(function(d, i) {
      d3.select(this).append("circle").attr("class", "orbit")
        .attr("r", d.R);
      d3.select(this).append("circle").attr("r", d.r).attr("cx",d.R)
        .attr("cy", 0).attr("class", "planet");
    });

  d3.timer(function() {
    var delta = (Date.now() - t0);
    svg.selectAll(".planet").attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "rotate(" + d.phi0 + delta * d.speed/200 + ")";
    });
  });
```

Comment: I know it's old but I came across this post. Is there a reason why the <g> AND the planet are rotating? I did some tests rotating only the planet and only the group and the results are the same, except a little bit slower (which is normal because I cut in half the rotation effect).

Answer (score 3):

I know this might come too late. But I do hope this can help future readers if they also are facing the same problem.
I created fiddles and add some explanation in here, hope it can help:

http://www.zestyrock.com/data-visualization/d3-rotate-object-around-the-center-object-part-2/

Here is the code:

```
var start = Date.now();

var mode = 0;

var svg = d3.select("#canvas")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500);

svg.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 50)
    .attr("cx", 250)
    .attr("cy", 250)
    .attr("fill", "#e05038");

var rotateElements = svg.append("g");

rotateElements.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 25)
    .attr("cx", 250)
    .attr("cy", 50)
    .attr("fill", "#f2b632")
    .attr("class", "orangeNode");

rotateElements.append("line")
    .attr("x1", 250)
    .attr("y1", 75)
    .attr("x2", 250)
    .attr("y2", 200)
    .attr("class", "edge")
    .attr("stroke", "grey");


d3.select("#start")
    .on("click", startAnimation);

function startAnimation() {
    if (mode === 0) {
        d3.timer(function() {
            var angle = (Date.now() - start);
            var transform = function() {
                return "rotate(" + angle + ", 250, 250)";
            };
            d3.selectAll(".orangeNode, .edge")
                .attr("transform", transform);

            if (mode === 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
        mode = 1;
    } else {
        mode = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: link is out of date

Comment: Very helpful, looks more intelligible than anything else I've found.