# Can I turn a D3 map projection clockwise around its centre point?

Tags: d3.js

How can I turn my map - if I can - clockwise by about 15-20 degrees, so that is looks like the map of the middle east I would see in an atlas?

Intuitively, `.rotate` looks like it should do it, but I've tried inserting different values and it just 'uncentres' the map.

The important bit of D3 code, I believe, is:

```
var projection = d3.geo.albers()
      .center([49.7, 27.4])
      .rotate([0, 0, 0])
      .parallels([12.6, 40])
      .scale(800)
      .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
```

(1)

[image]

Thanks.

---

(2)

[image]

I'm trying to replicate a map the looks like this (2) - just because it is what people are familiar with seeing in a regular atlas.

Comment: You could simply rotate the container.

Comment: ...but I cannot spin the projection around clockwise, right?

Comment: You should be able to do that as well.

Comment: You need to center the map in the div in which it is projected for this to work.

Comment: It is centered isn't it? via `.center([49.7, 27.4])` and then `.translate([width / 2, height / 2])`

Comment: This may help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872687/how-to-rotate-an-object-around-the-center-in-d3-js

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not knowing what you have tried thus far using [`projection.rotate()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#rotate) I still think this method will give the desired result. For example, a clockwise rotation by 20 degrees around LAT=49.7N, LON=27.4E as specified in your example could be done by:

```
projection.rotate([-49.7,-27.4,-20])
```

I set up a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/OmD3xL8C0YRbdn6n6u5b?p=preview) demonstrating the outcome.

---

#### Update

If you are not bound to using the Albers projection, there might be other options giving results which better fit your needs of

> what people are familiar with seeing in a regular atlas.

I looked it up in three atlases where the Arabian Peninsula was depicted using the equirectangular projection which looks like your desired output:

```
var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular()
    .rotate([-49.7,-27.4])
```

You just center on LAT=49.7N, LON=27.4E by applying `.rotate([-49.7,-27.4])` without the need to further roll the projection, i.e. you won't have the third element in the array supplied to `rotate()`. See my updated [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/OmD3xL8C0YRbdn6n6u5b?p=preview). To me this looks like what I would expect it look when seeing it in an atlas.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. Your values make the map in (2) above. I changed the map scale to 400, otherwise the values would just produce a blank page.

Comment: How did look it up in three atlases? Do you mean you were able to find three D3 examples projecting the Arabian Peninsula? Thanks.

Comment: I did this in *real life*! I went to the shelf, took out my three atlases, looked up the Arabian Peninsula and checked what projections were used plotting those maps. How could people even live prior to the invention of the internet ;-)

Comment: I didn't know atlases contained that kind of info. Thanks - good to know for the future!